# How can I read a PDF document and use a dictionary at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Could anybody point we to a way how could I read a PDF from Chrome and use a dictionary (e.g.  English dictionary extensions from Google)?

I wish to double click a word and choose "translate" (or something similar). Right now, I have to copy every unknown word to clipboard which is not what I want.

Comment: I wanted to point out is that in OS X you can [do this from every program](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hMN1e.png). Thinking about it, in my office (on Windows PCs) they use third-party software which claims to do the same, yet it is paid. So I guess you still want to do this for free (using Google, as you said)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several other extensions in the Chrome Web Store which do translation and definitions. The mechanism the extension uses to show translations determines whether it will work in Chrome's PDF viewer. Extensions which add an option to the right-click menu will work in the Chrome PDF viewer, while the extension you mentioned just depends on clicking on the word, which does not work. A couple that I tried (just from a quick search):

- [Right Click and Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gcgilaljhajcjdbgdoidofbjonkjikfm?hc=search&hcp=main): free, 4.5 stars, 9.3k users
- [Reference.com dictionary lookup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeepadhockifhkeglihhapjdhkcpcfal?hc=search&hcp=main): free, 5 stars, 800 users

[image: chrome right-click dictionary lookup]

Both of these worked fine in the built-in PDF viewer, as shown above. If your PDFs are opening in an Acrobat plugin, you'll want to disable that so that you can use the built-in one. You can do this by going to `chrome://plugins` and clicking `Disable` next to `Adobe Acrobat`. Make sure that `Chrome PDF Viewer` is enabled.

Comment: The second one works for me (first menu appears in built-in PDF reader, but doesn't work)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try converting the PDF to HTML then just open it with chrome. It may not work with file:// protocol, so you might have to put it on a local server (xampp on windows) and access it like any website (eg. localhost/my_pdfs/book13.pdf). There are plenty of online converters. I've tried this one http://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter, it separates each page into a separate html file which is named by the page name (eg. page 66 is 066.html) and it has a next previous navigation menu on the bottom. But you could always google around and try others and see what kind of conversion output you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate OS X's system wide dictionary/wikipedia lookup with a nifty little program called [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/). It's cross-platform and compatible with a variety of different dictonary formats, including openbabel and stardict. It can also be asily configured to lookup phrases online, e.g. on wikipedia/wiktionary. That's just the tip of the iceberg, though. It's completely customizable and has tons of useful features - much more so than OS X's dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

i use the website to convert pdf to html like Keeper Hood said and use this extension --> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cambridge-dictionaries-on/oaioomolanclklopkbfkhbmjeddbgdbj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

it's the extension from cambridge dictionary and just double click the word in html page, very easy. Good luck :>

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImTranslator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imtranslator-google-trans/noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh?hl=en) Chrome extension, it's powered by Google Translate.

It doesn't pop-up the translation of the selected text with just double-click like "Google Dictionary" extension on web pages (not in PDF); you need to mark the word or text, then right click the selected text and select "ImTranslator" in the menu.

It will pop-up a small window with translation of the text. ImTranslation has autodetection of the language, or you can make your own fixated settings.

I am suggesting this extension to translate words and text when opening PDFs in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin really convenient [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja).Just Double click on the word

Answer (score 0):

The Google translate Chrome plugin works only when the file is on server (not on your hard drive) and does not work with pdf files.

A solution is to move the file to a server and make it something else than a pdf.

You can do that link this:

- If you have a book in another language than yours on your hard drive go to [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) (free online conventer) send them your book, choose to change format to HTML.
- After a few minutes check you email box wher you'll find the changed document.
- Upload the HTML file to your website or (if you don't have one) create a site on some free hosting provider and put it there.

You can now go to thet document with your browser and use Google translate.